# Showing continuity of a function by epsilon delta

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, limits, continuity, epsilon-delta

I have the function

$$f(x)=
\begin{cases}
x^2 \sin\left(\displaystyle\frac{1}{x}\right) & \text{if } x\ne 0 \\
0 & \text{if }x=0
\end{cases}
$$

and I have to show that it is continuous at $x_0=0$. I think they want me to use epsilon delta argument. Can somebody help?

Comment: Just put $\delta=\min {\{\epsilon, 1}\}$

Answer (score 3):

I don't think they want $\delta-\epsilon$ proof. Im pretty sure that they want to proof the existence of $\lim_{x\to 0} f(x)$ and after show that 
$$\lim_{x\to 0} f(x)=0=f(0)$$
Aftter that you can conclude the continuity for the function!

Comment: ... and proving the existence of that limit is an $\epsilon$-$\delta$ proof. It might be camouflaged as a squeeze theorem, or anything else, but somewhere deep down there is an $\epsilon$-$\delta$ no matter what you do.

Comment: @Arthur If you look at it that way, *everything* proving continuity is an $\epsilon-\delta$ proof.

Comment: I know it. But also this type of exersise usually its been made to teach about the Lateral Limits.

Comment: @5xum I know, kind of like any proof of a statement like "For any natural number $n$, ..." is induction deep down.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** use the squeeze method between $-x^2$ and $x^2$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:since $|\sin t|\le|t|$ for every t.
See that 
$$|f(x)|\le|x|$$